# Payara server showing 404 when starting in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, http-status-code-404, payara

I have this Java REST API service project that is running fine in eclipse using payara glassfish server backend, VueJs front end.
When starting the server it runs fine without any issues, but when I want to debug my code and restart the server in debug mode the service shows HTTP Status 404 - Not Found (even though it was working fine before in debug mode)

I have been struggling with this issue for the past few days, I tried to reboot, adding/removing from server, deleted my payara and put it back.
is there any configuration in eclipse that I'm missing? or another way to debug my rest service?

Please help

[payara 404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5CYW.png)

Comment: What does the Console, or Payara's log, indicate during startup when you try to Debug?

Comment: @nitind Hi, here is the server log thant in hangs on: [2022-08-21T08:34:11.582+0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=FelixStartLevel] [timeMillis: 1661060051582] [levelValue: 800] [[
  D:\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles does not exist, please create it.]]